# Android ImageView stretches image

Tags: android, imageview, aspect-ratio, stretch

I've searched and searched and nothing seems to work to avoid my banner from stretching.
I've saved multiple instances of the banner in the drawabled folders. The width of the image is:

- xxhdpi: 1440px
- xhdpi: 960px
- hdpi: 720px
- mdpi:480px

When I run the app on a device with a screen width op 1080px (eg. nexus 5) the image is stretched..

The layout I'm using is a vertical linearlayout with the banner in an imageview on top.
I've tried changing the scaleType, layout_width/height and adjustViewBounds properties but nothing seems to work..

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/smos_bg"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/top" >       
</ImageView>
```